# InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 probably unsupported type

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

i am trying to select an item from DB table using variable from optionmenu:

```
        c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories")
        llist = c.fetchall()        

        add_item_quan = Label(add_item_frame, text='الكمية ', bg='#d3e4ec', fg='#4422ee')
        add_item_quan.config(font='Aerial 12 bold')
        add_item_quan.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=10, padx=10)    

        item_cat = StringVar()
        add_item_cat_list_name = OptionMenu(add_item_frame, item_cat, *llist)
        add_item_cat_list_name.config(width=50, fg='white', bg='#4422ee')
        add_item_cat_list_name.grid(row=4, column=1)


        def add_new_item():
            c.execute("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category_name = (?)", (item_cat, ))
            item_cat_id = c.fetchall()
            c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE id = (?) ", (item_cat_id, ))
            item_categ = c.fetchall()
            item_name = itemsname.get()
            itemsquan = int(itemsquan1)
            item_quant = itemsquan
            c.execute("INSERT INTO items (item_name, quan, item_category VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                      (item_name, item_quant, item_categ, ))

        add_item_button = Button(add_item_frame, text='مــوافــق', fg='white', bg='#4422ee',                          command=add_new_item)
        add_item_button.grid(row=1, pady=10, padx=10)
```

every time it  gives me the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "G:/Python/warehouse/main.py", line 126, in add_new_item
c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE id = (?) ", 
(item_cat_id, ))
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

the data base takes text and integers as data type:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`item_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
`quan`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
`item_category` TEXT
);
```

Other solutions were telling to change the text types in every var to suit the DB but it didn't work, I tried it as :

```
        def add_new_item():
        c.execute("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category_name = (?)", (str(item_cat), ))
        item_cat_id = c.fetchall()
        c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE id = (?) ", (int(item_cat_id), ))
        item_categ = c.fetchall()
        item_name = itemsname.get()
        itemsquan = int(itemsquan1)
        item_quant = itemsquan
        c.execute("INSERT INTO items (item_name, quan, item_category VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                  (str(item_name), int(item_quant), str(item_categ), ))
```

And then it gave me the same error again

Comment: done, please check the updated part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item_cat_id` is the result of the first `fetchall()` and is therefore a list of tuples. Sqlite has no idea what to do with that.

You could use `fetchone()` and indexing to get the actual ID and pass that in instead:

```
c.execute("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category_name = (?)", (item_cat, ))
item_cat_id = c.fetchone()[0]
```

However, it's hard to understand why you are doing these queries at all. You first ask the ID of the category with a specific name, then you ask for the name of the category with that returned ID. Not surprisingly, you will get back the name you started with, which seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Frist thanks for ur answer,,,the reason am doing this that the category name is editable in the user interface and i want to use the id to bind the name to another table so that whenever they change the category name it doesn't affect the other table ,specially in reports

Comment: None of that makes sense. `item_categ`, once you've sorted out the type issues, will be exactly the same as `item_cat`.